# How to find a string right after the searched string from a text file using Java?

Tags: java

I have text file in which I have following content.

```
Name Sahar Hassan
Age 26
```

I have wrote a Java code to find the location of the word "Name" and it works fine. I want to output the string right after the word "Name", that is "Sahar Hassan".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

File file = new File("somefilepath");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
String name = null;
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("Name"))
        name = line.substring(5);
}
// The variable "name" will be the name you seek (or be null if line not found)
```

Comment: Which package to import for Scanner?

Comment: @user648164 Added import statements you'll need

Answer (score 2):

You could use `indexOf` and search for the newline character (starting from the index of `Name`). Like this:

```
String str = "Name Sahar Hassan\nAge 26";
int nameIndex = str.indexOf("Name");            // What you say you already have.

int newLineIndex = str.indexOf("\n", nameIndex);

// Extract part after "Name"
String name = str.substring(nameIndex + 5, newLineIndex);

System.out.println(name);  // Prints "Sahar Hassan"
```

Comment: I will be inputting a text file. The code should read the string "Name" from the text file and output the word right after. Thanks

Comment: You already wrote that in the question.  What is the point of repeating it?

Comment: Andrew Thompson, In this answer, a String is used, Instead of that I have to pass an entire file. I would like to know how could I do that